# commandLink to update oncomplete's text before launching oncomplete

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I've got a tricky problem. I need to submit a form and update a map (with one click) with the data from the form, that just has been submitted. Now, what it does is: submitted data is up to date but the map's data is from the last call. The idea is for the update to be called before oncomplete somehow.

Here is the code:

```
<h:panelGroup layout="block" id="addressBlock" >            
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="geolabels, geoinputs" id="addressInputs">
            Straße <h:inputText styleClass="sidebar-input" value="#{search.searchContainer.geoCodeSearch.adresse}" /> 
            Plz <h:inputText styleClass="sidebar-input" value="#{search.searchContainer.geoCodeSearch.plz}" />
            Ort <h:inputText styleClass="sidebar-input" value="#{search.searchContainer.geoCodeSearch.ort}" />
        </h:panelGrid>      
        <p:commandLink styleClass="btn" value="#{messages['global.search']}" process="@this, addressInputs"
            action="#{search.searchContainer.geoCodeSearch.geoCode()}" update="geoCodeResult, addressBlock"
            oncomplete="updateMap('#{dataForMap}', true);" />   
</h:panelGroup>
```

Comment: It's a bit confusing for me. I suspect a bad design issue here but there's not enough information to be sure of that. Eg. instead of `#{search.searchContainer.geoCodeSearch.geoCode()}` why don't you make a call `#{someBean.searchAndUpdate}`?

Comment: Im porting this project from JSF 1.x in RichFacet to JSF 2 in Primefaces, that's why it's a bit cluttered. It used to be in a4j:form and was working the way i wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a normal behavior, the `#{dataForMap}` is processed at render time, not at update time.

This should do the trick :

```
<p:commandLink styleClass="btn" value="#{messages['global.search']}" process="@this, addressInputs" action="#{search.searchContainer.geoCodeSearch.geoCode()}" update="geoCodeResult, addressBlock, dataForMap" /> 

<h:panelGroup id="dataForMap">
    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{dataForMap ne null}">
        <script>
            updateMap('#{dataForMap}', true);
        </script>
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:panelGroup>
```

The `#{dataForMap}` will be updated and the script executed after the DOM is updated.

Comment: Thanks Alexandre, that's a nice and simple solution. The thing is however, that i'm launching this JS empty on page load, and that creates an error in console. It means I need to build in additional null checks and it's not so elegant any more.

Comment: that's what i wanted to avoid. I've got several units with this call on one page (depending on the data I put in), and if i go this way they'll all be true even though i launch only one of them. That's why the oncomplete call has been in commandLink itself.

Comment: @Kuba when you are saying several units, you mean that `<p:commandLink />` is inside an iterating component? If so, the `<h:panelGroup />` should be at the same place, IDs will be different and only the right one will be updated.

Comment: they're not in a repeat, they call the same function though, which relies on data submitted earlier. I went with making the call a function and it worked, not that elegant but hey... :-) thanks a lot Alexandre!

Comment: You are welcome, if ever you find a better solution feel free to add it and accept it!